# Drupal 7 Captcha in all webforms or per content type webforms

Tags: 7, webforms, captcha

I am on D7.

I have a content type that is webform enabled.

**Requirement**
I need to implement captcha for all the webforms for nodes of this content type.

**Problem**
In D7, you are supposed to give the form_id in the settings page to get captcha in the form, however I will have loads of forms with all different form_ids.

I am using the [Captcha](http://drupal.org/project/captcha) module.

Is there any way to implement my requirement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could add the following code to your template.php

```
if (strstr($form_id, 'webform_client_form')) {
        $form['my_captcha_element'] = array(
            '#type' => 'captcha',
            '#captcha_type' => 'image_captcha/Image',
        );
    }
```

this should be placed inside the yourthemename_form_alter

Comment: Thanks. I just got this solution, got it working, came back to answer my own question and saw that you already have. :) Thanks for the help nonetheless.

Comment: To have your custom code respect the permissions set for those people who can skip CAPTCHA add the following to your logic: 


if ((strstr($form_id, 'webform_client_form')) && !(user_access('skip CAPTCHA'))) {
    $form['my_captcha_element'] = array(
      '#type' => 'captcha',
      '#captcha_type' => 'default',
    );
  }

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can put this code in a custom module:

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_form_alter().
*/
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (preg_match("/^webform_client_form_[0-9]+$/",$form_id) && user_is_logged_in() == FALSE) {
    $form['my_captcha_element'] = array(
      '#type' => 'captcha',
    );
  }
}
```

Source: https://drupal.org/node/255795

Answer (score 1):

To have your custom code respect the permissions set at admin/people/permissions for those people who can skip CAPTCHA, add the following to your logic:

```
if ((strstr($form_id, 'webform_client_form')) && !(user_access('skip CAPTCHA'))) {
    $form['my_captcha_element'] = array(
      '#type' => 'captcha',
      '#captcha_type' => 'default',
    );
  }
```